# Attach labels to items in TFS from the PowerBuilder IDE?

Tags: tfs, powerbuilder

We do this using the `Advanced` button on the checkin dialog now (with `Merant`, `nee PVCS`) but the `Advanced` button is disabled when I set `TFS` as my `SCC` provider.  Is there a switch we can flip on either side to enable this?

- Or do we need to write some custom extension?
- Or can I get the `TFS changeset` number to associate with the change in PB?
- Or am I coming at doing selective builds entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve what we want by creating a Note field in TFS and making it required on check in.  The SCC interface will make the TFS check-in dialog appear & force the developer to enter a value in the field.  We can then use the Note to find the associated changeset & do extracts based on the changeset.    Thanks to all who looked at this.

Comment: thanks for posting the answer, this is (academically) interesting.  We're using PowerBuilder with PVCS 6.8 at present and may be moving